# iOS:Subclassing UIPickerView not loading in the main view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, uipickerview

I'm trying to subclass UIPickerView but is not loading in the main view.

Here is my code:

```
//Picker.h:
@interface Picker : UIPickerView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

//Picker.m:
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return 3;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return @"bla";
}
```

This the code on my viewController:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    self.myPicker = [[Picker alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:_myPicker];
}
```

Any of you knows why the picker is not loading on my view?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `viewDidAppear:` is executed?  Have you set the data source for the Picker? (if not, it looks like you want it to use itself as the datasource, which is unusual, but if so you might want to do this in `initWithFrame`)?  Do you get any errors logged?

Comment: @op pls see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>` in header of Picker.h.

Then, assign delegate to your own Picker object.

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];   
   if (self) {
      self.delegate = self;    // <-- add this line
   }   
   return self; 
}
```